# After over 1,000 successful calls, getting "An existing connection was forcibly closed"

Tags: .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-standard-2.0

I am doing some load testing of client and server code.  As it gets going, the first 1,000 calls are just fine.  But (on some runs), I start getting the following exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.  
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..  
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Some searching around shows that a common solution is to add the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But this seems to be a fix for when none of the calls work.  In my situation, I can get 1,000+ successful calls through before I start getting the above exception.

My real purpose in asking is that after this starts happening, I get a lot of failures of the same kind.

I am wondering if my `HttpClient` is in a faulted state after this happens?  If it is, how do I fix that?  (My `HttpClient` is static and if it fails, then all my calls will fail.)

Note: My code runs as a NuGet that needs to run in .Net Framework 4.7 and .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: Make sure you are using the `SendAsync` method on `HttpClient`, never use `GetAsync`, `PostAsync`... never modify the `Default...` properties when sharing `HttpClient` between many concurrent requests.

Comment: @Andy - I am using PostAsync.  Why is that bad?

Comment: I use `SendAsync` strictly because I like each request to have it's own header dictionary. That way if something modifies the `Default...` properties, it won't affect your calls. You aren't disposing your HttpClient and re-alloc'ing it each time right? May be a dumb question, but I swear i have seen this before and it was because someone was using multiple HttpClients or disposing/re-alloc'ing them each time.

Comment: @Andy - I see your reasoning.  My `HttpClient` is a static object that gets allocated at "static time" and lives the whole duration of the application.  That is the reason for my question.  I want to know if the connection for the `HttpClient` can get into a faulted state and I need to clean up and get a new one made.

Comment: I had a non .NET process calling a .NET service in AWS, using a persistent connection.  Every 1000th call failed, and I had to close and re-open the pipe.  Never did figure out if it was something in .NET or something in AWS.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I see you are posting about a load-testing and you are up to the 50K mark now (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456460/poor-net-core-service-response-times-halfway-through-load-test) Is this the same project?

Comment: @andy - this is a related, but different issue.  I posted an answer that I believe was what got us past this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue was due to WSO2 API Manager limiting the number of connections.  We change some settings on the WSO2 servers and this issue went away.  (I don't know the changes as the WSO2 admin made them.)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be anything about your code, that's the host refusing the connection, it could either be down because of the too many requests you sent it or, more probably, it has rate limited you.