# Poor .Net Core Service Response Times Halfway Through Load Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am running some load tests of my .Net Core 2 service and I am getting results that I am trying understand.

Here is a graph of a few of my runs:

[image: Call Times Under Load]
X-Axis = Calls
Y-Axis = Seconds for the `HttpClient.PostAsync` call to return

Basically, it handles most any load I throw at it up to about 55,000 calls (DOP in the key stands for Degree of Parallelism for the client).

But around 55K calls, the service starts to take a very long time.  (They Y-Axis is in seconds, not milliseconds.)

The service is very simple.  All it does is take the payload, serialize it and put it on a RabbitMQ queue:

```
using (var channel = _connection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: _QueueName, durable: true, exclusive: false,
        autoDelete: false, arguments: _QueueArguments);

    IBasicProperties props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
    props.ContentType = "text/plain";
    props.DeliveryMode = 2;
    var jsonOptions = new Options(dateFormat: DateTimeFormat.ISO8601);
    string message = Jil.JSON.Serialize<LogEvent>(logEvent, jsonOptions);
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: _QueueName, basicProperties: props, body: body);
}
```

If I give the service a break, then it can start at the very fast speed again (leading me to think it is not a memory leak).

My service is hosted in IIS (in case that matters).

**Any ideas on what could be going wrong around the 55K call mark?**

Comment: How fast are you sending the requests to your service? Are you bogging down the IIS ApplicationPool queue? (https://www.eginnovations.com/blog/top-7-net-application-performance-problems/) "A hard hang (IIS issue): Happens at the beginning of the request processing pipeline – where the request is queued. Because of an application deadlock, all available threads could get blocked, causing subsequent incoming requests to end up in a queue waiting to be serviced. This can also happen when the number of active requests exceed the concurrency limit configured on the IIS Server."

Comment: ... "Such a hang would manifest as requests getting timed out and receiving 503 Service Unavailable errors. A hard hang affects all URLs and the whole web application itself."